# Docker IPV6 routing

Tags: docker, ipv6

My host has ipv6 which works fine.  But my containers cant connect out on ipv6.

`Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40`

/etc/network/interfaces  (host)

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
address 2001:xxxx:5000:20::0010
netmask 64
gateway 2001:xxxx:5000:20::1
```

/etc/docker/daemon.json

```
{
    "ipv6": true,
    "fixed-cidr-v6": "2001:xxxx:5000:20::/64",
    "default-gateway-v6": "2001:xxxx:5000:20::1"
}
```

sysctl (host)

```
net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

docker run -it alpine ash -c "ip -6 addr show dev eth0; ip -6 route show; ping6 google.com"

```
259: eth0@if260: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 state UP 
    inet6 2001:xxxx:5000:20::242:ac11:2/64 scope global flags 02 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:acff:fe11:2/64 scope link tentative 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2001:xxxx:5000:20::/64 dev eth0  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev eth0  metric 256 
default via 2001:xxxx:5000:20::1 dev eth0  metric 1024 
ff00::/8 dev eth0  metric 256 

PING google.com (2a00:1450:4009:801::200e): 56 data bytes
```

Ping just hangs

Answer (score 1):

Change the /64 to an /80.

/etc/docker/daemon.json

```
{
    "ipv6": true,
    "fixed-cidr-v6": "2001:xxxx:5000:20::/80",
}
```

You may need to switch on

```
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.proxy_ndp=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `--network host` to your docker run command. This will give your container access to all interfaces on the host.

From docker docs: 

`Note: --network="host" gives the container full access to local system services such as D-bus and is therefore considered insecure.`

Comment: It's a bit of a hack.  I want docker to work as it's supposed to.   In this scenario, to get an individual ipv6 address, it would need to be configured inside the container.